# JQuery more/less toggle

Tags: jquery

I have cobbled together the following toggle to show the first paragraph with a more botton as a span inside the first paragraph.  When more is clicked the other paragraphs are shown and the more button gets hidden, however when the less button is clicked I need the more button to return.. can you help?

```
   <script>
    $('div#introduction').each(function(){
     var NODES = $(this).find('p').length;
     if(NODES>0){
      $(this).find('p:first').addClass('first');
      $(this).find('p:last').addClass('last');
      $('#introduction p.first').append('&nbsp;<span class="more"><a class="toggle">More</a></span>');
      $('#introduction p.last').append('&nbsp;<span class="less"><a class="toggle">less</a></span>');
      $('#introduction p').hide().slice(0,1).addClass('fixed').show();
      $('.toggle').click(function(){
       $( ".more" ).hide();
       $('p:not(.toggle,.fixed)').toggle();
       $(this).text(function(_, ML){
        return ML === 'Less' ? 'More' : 'Less';
       });
      });
     }
    });
   </script>
```

Many thanks in advance

Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be enough to replace this:

```
$( ".more" ).hide();
```

with this:

```
$( ".more" ).toggle();
```

...and then remove the code that changes the text such that your click handler ends up like this:

```
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
     $( ".more" ).toggle();
     $('p:not(.toggle,.fixed)').toggle();
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dXJrr/

And since then all you're doing is toggling stuff you can reduce your click handler to one line:

```
      $('.more, p:not(.toggle,.fixed)').toggle();
```

...though you can get a prettier effect like this:

```
     $('.more').toggle();
     $('p:not(.toggle,.fixed)').slideToggle();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dXJrr/2/

Comment: +1. Better approach. I think the text toggle part (present in the question) is not required because of the presence of one `a` for first and one for last.

Comment: Thanks @Harry. Yes, code to change the text only makes sense if that element is _not_ hidden.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, the below is what you need.

```
  $('div#introduction').each(function () {
      var NODES = $(this).find('p').length;
      if (NODES > 0) {
          $(this).find('p:first').addClass('first');
          $(this).find('p:last').addClass('last');
          $('#introduction p.first').append('&nbsp;<span class="more"><a class="toggle">More</a></span>');
          $('#introduction p.last').append('&nbsp;<span class="less"><a class="toggle">Less</a></span>');
          $('#introduction p').hide().slice(0, 1).addClass('fixed').show();
          $('.more').click(function () {
              $('p:not(.toggle,.fixed)').toggle();
              $(".less").show();
              $(".more").hide();
          });
          $('.less').click(function () {
              $('p:not(.toggle,.fixed)').toggle();
              $(".more").show();
              $(".less").hide();
          });
      }
  });
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E7JHg/)

Comment: Thank you Harry, I 'fiddled' with that for hours.

Comment: @Stuart: Always glad to be of help mate :) I was about to say that you should have accepted nnnnnn's solution because that is the better one. Nice to see you have already done that too :)